# Go back to a previous domain in Firefox history

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

Is there a way to set up Firefox that allows you to go back to a previously visited domain?

Let's say you found a link on reddit to Boston.com's Big Picture blog. You go through 20 pages of pictures. You don't want to click back through all of them. You just want a one click back button that lets you go straight back to reddit.com.

Maybe through some Firefox add-on?

Comment: (Though tagged for Firefox: Safari used to have this built-in, named "Snapback". Nowadays that's only used for search results though.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[domainav](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8871) is your ticket!

Comment: This add-on no longer works in Firefox (at least as of Firefox 50). `domainav` was last updated 6 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that I'll just end up going back to where I started, I just middle-click to open that first link in a new tab.  That's not to suggest that some people wouldn't find it useful to be able to navigate back to the most recent change in base level domain.  (Or, perhaps, by configuration, to the most recent change in full domain name.)

To clarify, based on the comments below, I posted this answer which doesn't directly answer @Jack's question because in my experience there are lots of people who don't know how easy it is to open links in a new tab (for example, recent convertees from IE6).  That, for me at least, precludes the need for this extension.  I try to follow the mantra of less is more, so when I can use existing functionality to solve my problem I prefer that over adding more extensions to Firefox.

Comment: Middle-click is my default way to open a link, unless I'm totally done with the page I'm on.

Comment: …except you didn't actually answer the question. Lazfish provides an extension that does *exactly* what the question asks for...

Comment: I think the StackExchange sites would be pretty barren overall if the guideline for answers was to be purely pedantic. Take a look around. There are answers throughout the StackExchange sites that don't directly answer the question, but do provide alternatives. Keep in mind, there is no prohibition in the FAQ or About on providing "alternative" answers. Feel free to vote my answer down if you don't think it was useful, but apparently someone thought it was useful. If you think I'm concerned about "reputation", I'm not. I'm happy to get and give help here, nothing more.

Comment: I believe this answer is useful and appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative could be to use the [CoolPreviews](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2207) extension that opens links in a popup window.

Answer (score 0):

I've used and loved [Rewind/Fastforward Buttons](http://piro.sakura.ne.jp/xul/_rewindforward.html.en) for years for exactly this purpose.  It occasionally conflicts with another add-on after a FireFox version upgrade, though, so I currently have it disabled.  But it's a great extension!

Edit: I just re-enabled it -- thanks for the reminder!